# Django REST Framework SessionAuthentication does not seem to work?

Tags: django, rest, session, authentication, frameworks

I configured a Django REST API for SessionAuthentication, TokenAuthentication and OAuth2Authentication for AJAX web apps (and native clients in the future).

Token en OAuth2 authentication work fine, but the behavior of the SessionAuthentication is not yet working like I would like it.

I have two REST APIs with an identical configuration at the moment:

http://api.sandbox.dev:8080/ and http://www.sandbox.dev:8080/api/

My AJAX web app is located on http://www.sandbox.dev:8080.

The code:

- Django settings: https://github.com/kristofvbk/sandbox-django/blob/master/sandbox/settings.py
- JavaScript REST client: https://github.com/kristofvbk/sandbox-django/blob/master/sandbox/www/static/js/jquery.rest.js
- AJAX web app: https://github.com/kristofvbk/sandbox-django/blob/master/sandbox/www/templates/ajax/session.html

Everytime when I make an AJAX call to the API on api.sandbox.dev from www.sandbox.dev I get an "403 Forbidden" error. I think I did all the right things to make things work cross-domain or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for any help or tips!

Kind regards,
Kristof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

jquery.rest.js

```
$.ajax({
    xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    ...
});
```

settings.py:

```
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ('www.sandbox.dev:8080', )

SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.sandbox.dev'
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.sandbox.dev'
```

Comment: Thanks mariodev - I almost got everything working now, but with these additional settings, I can only GET (read) data from api.sandbox.dev on www.sandbox.dev through AJAX. When I try to POST, PUT or DELETE something, I always get "403 FORBIDDEN" with as message in the response '{"detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."}'. I also added pages with OAuth2 and token authentication for the same API on api.sandbox.dev and with the same CSRF token in the AJAX REST client, but no problems there.

Comment: I also updated the most important files listed above in GitHub.

Comment: See updated post, those two domain names are the only changes I did to your latest repo and POST work fine..

Comment: Thanks for the tips, mariodev! That was indeed the last missing piece of the puzzle. :-) Everything works now (session, OAuth2 and token auth), awesome!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Apache mod_wsgi to serve it, you might need to add the following to your VirtualHost config file because the authorization header is stripped out by mod_wsgi.  You'll need to add the following to your VirtualHost configuration:

```
WSGIPassAuthorization On
```

Further reference: http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication.html#unauthorized-and-forbidden-responses

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using Django's built-in web server (through "python manage.py runserver"). I'll remember it for putting everything in production.